# React testing library: test failed style (Select + Form Control from MUI)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-testing-library, jest-dom

**The problem**

I'm trying to test the border is red if the component is in error state, but it's failing in local machine, **but not in *codesandbox***

**What I have tried:**

- Check whether there is a difference between `FormHelperText` and `fieldSet` in styling
- Tried to replicate over *codesandbox*
- read docs and research found a similar case but uses different styling: https://twitter.com/hieptuanle5/status/1051811353176858625

**Code**
Component with error state set to `true`

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import FormHelperText from "@material-ui/core/FormHelperText";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";

export const SelectInput = () => {
  return (
    <FormControl error={true} variant="outlined">
      <Select />
      <FormHelperText> test </FormHelperText>
    </FormControl>
  );
};
```

Testing

```
import { render, screen, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
import { SelectInput } from "../App";
test("test form control error state", async () => {
  render(<SelectInput />);

  const fieldSet = screen.getByRole("group", { hidden: true });
  const helperText = screen.getByText("test");
  await waitFor(() => expect(fieldSet).toBeInTheDocument());

  expect(helperText).toHaveStyle(`color: #f44336;`);
  expect(fieldSet).toHaveStyle(`border-color: #f44336;`);
});
```

codesanbox link
[https://codesandbox.io/s/rtl-mui-select-test-style-border-tekgl?file=/src/**test**/select.test.js:0-549](https://codesandbox.io/s/rtl-mui-select-test-style-border-tekgl?file=/src/__test__/select.test.js:0-549)

**EDIT 2 Local machine error logs:**

```
  ● should accept error string props

    expect(element).toHaveStyle()

    - Expected

    - border-color: #f44336;
    + border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);

    >  97 |   expect(fieldSet).toHaveStyle(`border-color: #f44336;`)
```

Any leads will be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: what's the error you receive in local env ?

Comment: Hi @aquinq thanks for the response, please see my edit :)

Comment: Thanks, the error is related to `should accept error string props ` test, but in the codesanbox the test is `test form control error state` ?

Comment: the test title may differ but the test are the same. One more thing that confuses me is the `helperText` is passing the test and having the `border-color:  #f44336;`